# MFC. Использование фильтра при работе с ODBC

Tags: c++, sql, mfc, odbc

Нужно из таблицы `Books` получить записи с полем `gener_id = 2`. С этим полем связана таблица `Genres`. Также с полем `author_id` в таблице Books связана таблица `Authors`. При использовании фильтра получаю ошибку.

Ошибка:
[image: Ошибка синтаксиса (пропущен оператор) в выражении запроса]

Фрагмент кода в обработчике нажатия кнопки:

```
m_pSet->m_strFilter = L"[Books].genre_id = '2'";
m_pSet->Requery();
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

а если так:

```
m_pSet->m_strFilter = L"[Books].genre_id = 2";
m_pSet->Requery();
```

Comment: Проблема была в другом. В выборке изначально было добавлено условие:  SELECT * FROM * WHERE * . При добавлении фильтра в запросе получалось два WHERE.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй поставить число без кавычек.